# Kendo Grid detail template is not working on loading grid again(second time) using ajax form post(MVC)

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc, kendo-grid

**Below is the function for creating kendo grid and in that different function is called for column option and data source and detail template**

```
     var kendoDataSource = currentOtherMerchant.model.dataSource();
        var columnsOptions = currentOtherMerchant.columnOptions();
        currentOtherMerchant.$el.kendoGrid({
            dataSource: kendoDataSource,
            columns: columnsOptions,
            dataBound: currentOtherMerchant.onDataBound,
            pageable: {
                refresh: true
            },
            detailTemplate: '<div class="tabstrip"><ul><li class="k-state-active" id="first">' + currentOtherMerchant.options.prompts.details + '</li></ul><div class="merchant-details"></div></div>',
            detailInit: currentOtherMerchant.detailInit,
            detailExpand: currentOtherMerchant.detailExpand,
            resizable: true,
            scrollable: true
        });
```

**Below is the function for detail template**

```
detailInit: function (e) {

        currentOtherMerchant.detailTab(e);
        currentOtherMerchant.animateTabStrip(e.detailRow);
    },
    detailExpand: function (e) {
        var grid = currentOtherMerchant.$el.data("kendoGrid");
        grid.collapseRow(grid.tbody.find(' > tr.k-master-row').not(e.masterRow));
        debugger;
    },
    /* Fetch details for expanded Pspid */
    detailTab: function (e) {
        var detailRow = e.detailRow;
        var ajaxData = { "PSPId": e.data.PSPId,
            "HashedParam": e.data.HashedParam
        };
        var ajaxParameters = { "ajaxData": ajaxData, "ajaxURL": currentOtherMerchant.model.attributes.urls.detailTemplateUrl, dataType: 'html' };
        grid_ajaxCall(ajaxParameters, function (data) {
            if (data != null) {
                currentOtherMerchant.genarateDetailTemplateId(detailRow, e);
                detailRow.find(".merchant-details").html(data);
            }
        });
    },
```

Please help to solve this issue.
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the solution for this,
This is issue because of kendo grid is not destroyed from dom on ajax form post
so i have used kendo grid destroy method before creating grid,so all the objects and events for grid is destroyed

```
  if (current.$el.find('#gridId').data().kendoGrid != undefined)
            current.$el.find('#gridid').data().kendoGrid.destroy();
```

Make kendo grid element empty

```
           current.$el.find('#girdid').empty();
```

Comment: God bless you mate! Had the same issue and was actually wondering if empty or destroy would help. I am sorry I can give you only 1 upvote.

Comment: that is working for me, i think for you also that work.